# How to search a numeric value in a database

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Let's say I have query structured like below which indicates dates

```
search.asp?date=091210
```

I want to find each record that includes `0912` string how can I inquire it on the link structure.

Comment: What database, and what is the data type of the column you want to search?

Comment: I'm guessing it's an address database, and the datatype is a string. I think the example is meant to be "search.asp?zip=90210". It's the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: 091210 = 9th December 2010 ...its can easily be a date

Comment: Surely Beverly Hills is more interesting than a recently past Thursday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourField LIKE '%0912%'
```

Comment: It should be noted that no known databases optimize LIKE '%%' queries... meaning that no indexes will be used. Only LIKE 'prefix%' are optimal, as you need a common prefix to use an index.

Comment: @Pestilence, I agree with you but OP said "includes", so I had to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, never trust anything that is given on a URL.
What you should do, is parse the date variable and split it up in a month, day and year part.
Be sure to do the necessary sanity checks.
Then you can issue a query like:
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE MONTH(dateColumn) = month AND YEAR(dateColumn) = year